# Convert parameter file to python dict or json and exclude certain parameters

Tags: python, dictionary, parsing, parameters

I have a parameter file formatted like this

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH=(example1,example2)
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=example
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT=example

SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=example

SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME=example


SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION=example
SSL_VERSION=example

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES=(example1)

SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION=example

WALLET_LOCATION=
(SOURCE=
(METHOD=FILE)
(METHOD_DATA=
(DIRECTORY=somedir)
```

I'm trying to load this file into python, change values for a certain key, and then save off the rest of the values.

Here's what I have so far...

```
# Open file to remove spaces from parameters,values
with open('tempfile', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# remove spaces
lines = [line.replace(' ', '') for line in lines]

# finally, write lines in the file
with open('tempfile', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)

# Change value in file, if found
d = {}
with open('tempfile') as f:
  d = dict(x.rstrip().split('=', 1) for x in f)
  print("dictionary before",d)
  d['SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES'] = '(somevalue)'
  print("dictionary after modification-", d)
```

Comment: How does what you "have so far" compare with what you want?

Comment: If this is something under your control, can you use a yaml or json or python based config file?

Comment: @ScottHunter it doesn't completely.

Comment: @JonSG - I can use whatever route possible. Just need to get it done. I was considering converting to json first then converting

Answer (score 0):

If I have the ability to define the config file, I would likely use json.

config.json:

```json
{
    "NAMES": {
        "DIRECTORY_PATH": ["example1", "example2"]
    },

    "SQLNET" : {
        "ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER": "example",
        "ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT": "example",
        "INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT": "example",
        "EXPIRE_TIME": "example",
        "AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES": ["example1"]
    },

    "SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION": "example",
    "SSL_VERSION": "example",

    "WALLET_LOCATION": {
        "SOURCE": {"METHOD" : "FILE"},
        "METHOD_DATA": {"DIRECTORY" : "somedir"}
    }
}
```

This makes reading and manipulating the data fairly easy.

```py
import json

with open("config.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file_in:
    config = json.load(file_in)

config["SQLNET"]["AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES"] = ["somevalue"]

with open("config.new.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file_out:
    json.dump(config, file_out, indent=4)
```

Of course you could write back to the original file if you wanted.

You should get a result like:

config.new.json:

```json
{
    "NAMES": {
        "DIRECTORY_PATH": [
            "example1",
            "example2"
        ]
    },
    "SQLNET": {
        "ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER": "example",
        "ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT": "example",
        "INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT": "example",
        "EXPIRE_TIME": "example",
        "AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES": [
            "somevalue"
        ]
    },
    "SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION": "example",
    "SSL_VERSION": "example",
    "WALLET_LOCATION": {
        "SOURCE": {
            "METHOD": "FILE"
        },
        "METHOD_DATA": {
            "DIRECTORY": "somedir"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ahh awesome. thanks for that. So I'll have to find a way to convert this to json now. How can I automatically convert to json now. Because I plan on running this for 100's of these config files

Comment: oh sorry, you don't control the config file format?  hmm what created these files?

Comment: These are database config files. I can't control the config file format. I just have to interpret it with whichever best way possible. Such as json, which I'm a fan of because of the structure.